# How to remove unsorted duplicate lines in Notepad++ using Regex

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have my file (link is in comment)
A Sample of Data
`Yn2STc5A`
`MBI1irwA`
`Yn2STc5A`
`agCGRvWu`
`KZIcwFII`
`414PGEBK`
`MBI1irwA`
`KZIcwFII`
`lln5OKRi`
`Yn2STc5A`
`6gCsLHJA`
`Yn2STc5A`
`MBI1irwA`
`KZIcwFII`
`MBI1irwA`
`22LYWQsX`
`22LYWQsX`
`Yn2STc5A`
`KZIcwFII`
`agCGRvWu`
`lln5OKRi`

This file has 528 lines, every line is a repetition of 13 lines, And the 13 lines is a code per a Team link.
I have used and searched many Regex
But only these two was a bit close to what I needed,
Find: `^(.{8}\n)([\S\s]+?\1)` and this too `^(.*)([\S\s]+?\1)`
Replace All: `$2`

But I have to press `Replace all` repetitively,  (47 times at least) to reach my goal...

My Desired Output should be out of complete file..
`1:22LYWQsX`
`2:414PGEBK`
`3:6gCsLHJA`
`4:C6C8JOnf`
`5:KZIcwFII`
`6:MBI1irwA`
`7:NQid5EnY`
`8:P68A94uk`
`9:Yn2STc5A`
`10:agCGRvWu`
`11:jbsO5Pzk`
`12:lln5OKRi`
`13:vWSvMjaa`

Thanks in advance

Comment: It means,  after `Replace all` it will only remove 41 occurrences, in second `Replace all` it will Remove 43 occurrences,  till this repetition reaches to  46/47 times, then it will give me this result ..... `jbsO5Pzk`  
`C6C8JOnf`  
`P68A94uk`  
`vWSvMjaa`  
`Yn2STc5A`  
`6gCsLHJA`  
`NQid5EnY`  
`22LYWQsX`  
`lln5OKRi`  
`agCGRvWu`  
`414PGEBK`  
`KZIcwFII`  
`MBI1irwA`

Comment: The `(?=)` lookforward won't let the engine remove anyline,  I just tested your code,  no benifit

Comment: I have tried a test with the complete sample data. There I have no hit for `WWeHbjJR` and only 13 lines in my result. Is that a typo in your question for the expected output?

Comment: I used Notepad++ standard functions for this in a second. Is the use of RegEx a mandatory requirement for you or an answer to your question?

Comment: It seems that your expected output is sorted. The simplest way is to sort the input file then delete 13 duplicate lines.

Comment: @help-info,  please share the code that worked,  if you got 13 lines it is still considered a correct answer... thanks

Comment: @Toto,  this is why I asked if there is a Regex for unsorted lines , my mobile editor doesn't support sorting lines ,  these 13 lines are a shortened team link for lichess, so the randomness is because these teams have played versus each others. Anyway I have found the solution online, but I'm still much curious to know if it is possible in Regex?

Comment: @Haji, as mentioned I did this by using Notepad++ standard functions (Edit > Line operations) BTW - you need to edit your question for the desired output (e.g. delte `9:WWeHbjJR` and renumber the following llines.)

Comment: @help-info the Regex is much appreciated,  if there is no regex, then I will accept the standar-function answer as well, Regards

Comment: @help-info I edited my question,  post your answer I will upvote it, if there was no Regex solution,  I will accept it as Correct answer, but a day later, since I will be waiting for a Regex solution ....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I recommend to use standard functions of Notepad++ (my version 8.1.9 64 bit) if possible for your needs.

- First open the sample data file (*.txt) by Notepad++
- From the main menu go to **Edit > Line Operations > Remove Duplicate Lines**
- Go to **Edit > Line Operations > Sort Lines Lexicographically Ascending**
- Format the result as desired for your needs.

***Interim result:***

[image]

Comment: Here is the link to file(https://www.mediafire.com/file/otdvfdkkjydlk0s/Teams_vs.txt/file)